# Building a method that reads and prints partially filled array in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, build

As part of my program I need to build a method that will read and print only the filled slots of the array no matter where they are.  By that I mean if there was an array length ten and only array[0] and array[9] were filled the method should read the entire array and only print whats been filled and not the zeros in between.

This is how the method will look

```
printArray( intList, countOfInts );
```

This is the method I've built:

```
static public int printArray( int[] intList, int countofInts)
 {
    for (countofInts = 0; countofInts < intList.length; countofInts++)
    { 
        System.out.print(intList[countofInts] + "\t ");
    }
    return countofInts;

 }
```

It works but it prints the whole array instead of just the slots that are filled.
How do I make it not print the slots of the array that aren't filled?

Comment: Check to make sure they are not empty. Also, you shouldn't overwrite a parameter that comes into your method.

Comment: instead of printing outright, check if a slot in the array actually is filled first and only print if that is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding the passed `countOfInts` value.

You have to change your loop statement and also, before that, you can add a check if the passed `countOfInts` is valid (otherwise, there is a great possibily an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` to be thrown in a case of passing an invalid `countOfInts` value).

```
if (countOfInts >= 0 && countOfInts <= intList.length) {
   for (i = 0; i < countofInts; i++) { 
       System.out.print(intList[i] + "\t ");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this if condition:

```
if(intList[countofInts]!=0)
     System.out.print(intList[countofInts] + "\t ");
```

now it only prints the filled slots because the default of int is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..!

```
>static public int printArray( int[] intList, int countofInts){
for (countofInts = 0; countofInts < intList.length; countofInts++)
{ if(intList[countofInts ]!=0)
    System.out.print(intList[countofInts] + "\t ");
}
return countofInts;}
```